# given a range X, N intervals and an overlap O, calculate interval size

Tags: algorithm, matlab

I have a range `X`. 
I want to divide this range in `N` intervals. 
I also want the intervals to overlap. 
Which algorithm allows me to find the size of my intervals?

Example:

```
Range   = 1;  % the data ranges between 0 and 1
N       = 5;  % the range is divided in 5 intervals.
Overlap = .5; % Two neighbouring intervals overlap by 50%

StepSize = ?;
```

Thank you very much

Comment: you may give an explicit example. you question's not very clear.  for example, 0.5 of the total size, total size of what? x? interval? total overlapped regions?

Comment: Did you make no progress on this problem? For example, did you determine the size of each interval? Assuming the overlap between each pair is the same, this is just a matter of arithmetic. And then, you can obviously place the end two intervals -- one at each end of the interval you're trying to cover. From there, it seems like you're almost done.

Comment: @paulHankin I am aware it´s fairly easy, but somehow I cannot find a good way to determine the size of each interval.

Comment: @shiping, i updated the question to make it more explicit. It was indeed ambiguous. Sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The formula is

```
s = x / (n + o - n * o)
```